# How can I retrieve the original File of a FileInputStream

Tags: java, file, virtual, fileinputstream

I need based on the APIs I use, to implement a method with an `InputStream` parameter (instance of `FileInputStream`) that will call a method with a `File` argument.

```
implementedMethod(InputStream is){
    FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream)is; //always works
    File f = (???) ????(???).???;
    calledMethod(f);
}
```

So how do I provide that `File` when all I have is a `FileInputStream`? I don't understand what a `FileChannel` or a `FileDescriptor` (both in `FIS`) are exactly and how they work.

I'm guessing that this can't be done and that I will have to actually write a (temp) file on the filesystem. If not, if I can create my file in memory instead with FileChannel or FileDescriptor, or even with something as `RandomAccessFile` (?) I'd like to know how...

Is it that constructing a readable `File` object requires it to exist somewhere on the disk? I find this odd...

Comment: Why would you want to want to do that? It's like calling the superclass from the subclass, it's bad practice. Perhaps you haven't modularized your problem correctly?

Comment: If you expect a FileInputStream, why not change the formal parameter type to `FileInputStream`. If you need a `File` change it to file and construct the stream yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the file name from a `FileInputStream`.

For all we know, the stream could have been constructed from a file descriptor representing, for example, a socket.

My recommendation would be to rethink your design.

Comment: well about redesigning I can't, as I said I have 2 APIs to connect, and I need a transformer do to so. I was hoping for some way to bypass the writing a file on the system process. It looks like it can't be avoided. Btw how can a socket generate a FileInputStream?
And more importantly, "Is it that constructing a readable File object requires it to exist somewhere on the disk? I find this odd..."

Answer (score 0):

You can of course bypass the API and, assuming it won't always work (depending on the JDK and the SecurityManager), use reflection:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the {@link File} associated to given {@link FileInputStream}, if possible.
 * @param inputStream the input stream.
 * @return the file.
 */
@Nullable
public File retrieveFile(@NotNull final FileInputStream inputStream)
{
    @Nullable final File result;

    @Nullable String path = null;

    try
    {
        @Nullable final Field field =
            inputStream.getClass().getDeclaredField("path");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        path = (String) field.get(inputStream);
    }
    catch (@NotNull final Throwable noFieldOrNoRights)
    {
    }

    if (path == null)
    {
        result = null;
    }
    else
    {
        result = new File(path);
    }

    return result;
}
```